# mysql update values in foreign key field value with parent key

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

in my database there is table name session and session_id is the primary key of that. and there is member table and member_id is the primary key. also there is relationship between two tables. session_id is the foreign key of member table. I want to update member_id with the same value of session_id while insert value into session table. anyone can help me with this??

Comment: Not clear. Update `member_id`?  You want to update member table after insert into session table?

Comment: yes i want to update member_id in member table after insert into session table

Comment: How do you get the `member _id`? You have mentioned that `member_id` is the primary key. So it must be auto incremented value. Why you want to insert member_id?

Comment: no i did not make member_id auto increment

Comment: Fine. Then what value you need to update into `member_id` field?

Comment: same value that come to session_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a MySQL trigger to accomplish this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON session FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE member
    SET member_id = NEW.session_id
END;
```